# I only see one of two printers shared by Windows 10 computer

Tags: printing, network-printer

I have a Windows 10 computer ("Computer A") with two USB printers ("Printer 1" and "Printer 2") attached to it. The printers are different models with different names, and are both shared so another Windows 10 computer ("Computer B") on the same network can print from both printers.

Computer B can see Printer 1, and I can add that printer to Computer B and print from it. The issue is that Printer 2 cannot be seen by Computer B to get added. Both printers function properly from Computer A.

Suggestions on how to make it where Computer B can see Printer 2 so that printer can be printed from over the network by Computer B?

Comment: Is the printer that cannot be seen limited to SMBv1?

Comment: @John Thank you for the reply. How do I check that the printer that cannot be seen is limited to SMBv1? For reference, I ran the following command in PowerShell, which returned False: Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Printer share names and make sure they are unique.  I believe you could manually connect to the printer using two slashes \ComputerName\PrinterName